# Link checker - need some help

Tags: php

I got this script called "rapidshare link checker v2 php by Bigfish"
At the moment the script checks the links inside $links =  " ". I would like it to check all the megaupload links on the page.
If that doesnt work it would be ok if you guys help me make some changes so the script ignores all code except megaupload links.

The script [link text](http://www.anitard.org/linkchecker.txt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the foreach loop add a conditional:

```
$pos = strpos($url,"megaupload");

if($pos === false)
{
 //skip checking
}
else
{
  //go ahead and do the checking
}
```

Comment: Does not work.
If i add a link ( <a href="test.php></a> ) inside the $links ="" i stil get error.

i added your code to my code like you told me but nothin happened.

$link = explode("\n",$links);

 foreach($link as $url){

 
 $pos = strpos($url,"megaupload");

 if($pos === false)
 {
  //skip checking
 }
 else
 {
   //go ahead and do the checking
 } 
 $url = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $url);

Comment: Wops. i shouldnt have pasted the script like that.
here: http://www.anitard.org/linkchecker.txt